Finite map of local rings satisfying certain properties is surjective
$\newcommand{\iM}{\mathfrak{m}}\newcommand{\iN}{\mathfrak{n}}$I'm working on the following exercise and am quite stuck.
Let $(A,\iM)$ and $(B,\iN)$ be local rings, and let $f:A\to B$ be a map of local rings making $B$ a finitely-generated $A$-module such that the induced map $A/\iM\to B/\iN$ is an isomorphism and the induced map $\iM\to\iN/\iN^2$ is surjective. I would like to deduce that $f$ is itself surjective.
I can show that $A\to B/\iN^2$ is surjective (this follows straight from the five lemma and the given hypotheses on $f$). A hint suggests showing that $A\to B/\iN^r$ is surjective for all $r$, but I am stuck getting even to $r=3$, since as far as I can tell this would require showing that the map $\iM^2\to \iN^2/\iN^3$ is surjective, and I do not yet see how to do this. I also am not sure I see how knowing $A\to b/\iN^r$ is surjective for all $r$ shows that $A\to B$ is surjective, since we'd still have to deal with $\bigcap_{r\geq 1}\iN^r$. The fact that we do not know that $A$ or $B$ is Noetherian seems to rule out a lot of possible tools I would otherwise consider using, so in the absence of any Noetherian hypothesis I am a little lost.
I would appreciate any hints or pointers.

Mmh, if we additionally assume that $\mathfrak n$ is finitely generated as an ideal, there are multiple ways to do this (You show that $A/\mathfrak m\to B/\mathfrak mB$ is surjective and the result follows from Nakayama. To show that this is surjective note that $\mathfrak n^2+\mathfrak m B=\mathfrak n$, so it follows from Nakayama if we assume $\mathfrak n$ finite. Alternatively if we want to use the hint: If $\mathfrak n$ is finite, $\mathfrak n^r\subset \mathfrak m B$ for some $r$ (use integrality argument), and then the map is surjective because $A\to B/\mathfrak n^r$ is.)

I have added a complete solution to my previous partial answer.  The key points are that $B/{\frak m}B$ is a finite dimensional algebra over $A/ {\frak m}$, and $B/A$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, giving you two places where you can use Nakayama's lemma.

To address the hint: For all $r$, the map $f$ induces a surjective map $A\to B/{\frak n}^r$.
Proof:
An element of ${\frak n}^r$ may be written as the sum of elements of the form $n_1n_2\cdots n_r$, with each $n_i\in {\frak n}$.  For each $i$ we may write $n_i=f(m_i)+n'_i$, with $n'_i\in {\frak n}^2$, $m_i\in {\frak m}$.  Note $f(m_i)\in {\frak n}$ for each $i$.  Multiplying out, we get $$(f(m_1)+n'_1)(f(m_2)+n'_2)\cdots (f(m_r)+n'_r)$$ is the sum of elements in ${\frak n}^{r+1}$ and $f(m_1m_2\cdots m_r)$.
Thus the map induced by $f$, ${\frak m}^r\to {\frak n}^r/{\frak n}^{r+1}$ is surjective.
We know any element $b\in B$ may be written $b=f(a)+n_1$ with $a\in A$ and $n_1\in {\frak n}$.
Then $n_1$ may be written $n_1=f(m_1) +n_2$ with $m_1\in {\frak m}$ and $n_2\in {\frak n}^2$.
Continuing in this way we eventually get $n_{r-1}=f(m_{r-1}) +n_r$ with $m_{r-1}\in {\frak m}^{r-1}$ and $n_r\in {\frak n}^r$.
Thus $$b= f(a)+f(m_1)+f(m_2)+\cdots+f(m_{r-1})+n_r= f(a')+n_r,$$
where $a'=a+m_1+m_2+\cdots+m_r\in A$ and $n_r\in {\frak n}^r$.
Note without the fact that $B$ is finitely generated over $A$, the map $f$ need not be surjective, even for Noetherian rings or even PID's:  Let $f\colon \mathbb{Z}_{(5)}\to \mathbb{Z}[i]_{(2+i)}$ be the natural inclusion of the integers localised at $(5)$, in the Gaussian integers localised at $(2+i)$.  Then $f$ is not surjective (the rationals do not contain a square root of $-1$), but $f$ satisfies all your hypotheses other than $B$ being finitely generated over $A$ (it is generated by $\frac1{(2-i)^k},\frac i{(2-i)^k}$, for $k\in \mathbb{N}$).

Full solution:
We know that $B/{\frak m}B$ is a finite dimensional local algebra over the field $A/{\frak m}$.  Let $\hat{\frak n}$ be the image of ${\frak n}$ in this algebra.
As this algebra is finite dimensional, we know $\hat{\frak n}\hat{\frak n}^k= \hat{\frak n}^k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$.  By Nakayama's lemma we then have $(1-n) \hat{\frak n}^k=0$ for some $n\in \hat{\frak n}$.  But $B/{\frak m}B$ is local, so $1-n$ is invertible, and we have $\hat{\frak n}^k=0$.  That is ${\frak n}^k\subseteq {\frak m}B$.
From our earlier reasoning, we know that any $b\in B$ may be written $b=f(a)+n_k$ where $n_k\in {\frak n}^k\subseteq {\frak m}B$.  That is $B=f(A)+ {\frak m}B$ as $A$-modules.
Now let $M=B/f(A)$, which is a finitely generated module over $A$.  We have ${\frak m}M= M$.  Again by Nakayama's lemma, there is some $m\in {\frak m}$ such that $(1-m)M=0$.  As $A$ is a local ring, $1-m$ is invertible, so $M=0$ as required.

Looking back at the comment by @leoli1, it lays much of the foundation of this answer, and should be acknowledged as a helpful influence.
